# TF30004: The New Team Project Wizard encountered an unexpected error while initializing the Microsoft.ProjectCreationWizard.Portal plug-in

Tags: visual-studio, team-foundation-server, windows

i get this error when i trying to create a new project in team project. The server is right, i check all ports. I don't now what i should do now, can't find any good information

```
2009-09-19 01:45:41Z | Module: Internal | Team Foundation Server proxy retrieved | Completion time: 0.338 seconds
2009-09-19 01:45:41Z | Module: Internal | The template information for Team Foundation Server "TFSServer01" was retrieved from the Team Foundation Server. | Completion time: 0.099 seconds
2009-09-19 01:45:41Z | Module: Wizard | Retrieved IAuthorizationService proxy | Completion time: 0.404 seconds
2009-09-19 01:45:41Z | Module: Wizard | TF30227: Project creation permissions retrieved | Completion time: 0.015 seconds
2009-09-19 01:45:44Z | Module: Engine | Thread: 5 | New project will be created with the "MSF for Agile Software Development - v4.2" methodology
2009-09-19 01:45:44Z | Module: Engine | Retrieved IAuthorizationService proxy | Completion time: 0 seconds
2009-09-19 01:45:44Z | Module: Engine | TF30227: Project creation permissions retrieved | Completion time: 0.01 seconds
2009-09-19 01:45:45Z | Module: Engine | Wrote compressed process template file | Completion time: 0.001 seconds
2009-09-19 01:45:46Z | Module: Engine | Extracted process template file | Completion time: 1.428 seconds
2009-09-19 01:45:46Z | Module: Engine | Thread: 5 | Starting Project Creation for project "TestProject" in domain "TFSServer01"
2009-09-19 01:45:46Z | Module: Engine | The user identity information was retrieved from the Group Security Service | Completion time: 0.045 seconds
2009-09-19 01:45:46Z | Module: Initializer | Thread: 5 | The New Team Project Wizard is starting to initialize the plug-ins.
2009-09-19 01:45:46Z | Module: CssStructureUploader | Thread: 5 | Entering Initialize in CssStructureUploader
2009-09-19 01:45:46Z | Module: CssStructureUploader | Thread: 5 | Initialize for CssStructureUploader complete
2009-09-19 01:45:46Z | Module: Initializer | Thread: 5 | The New Team Project Wizard successfully Initialized the plug-in Microsoft.ProjectCreationWizard.Classification.
2009-09-19 01:45:46Z | Module: Rosetta | Thread: 5 | Entering Initialize in RosettaReportUploader
2009-09-19 01:45:48Z | Module: Rosetta | Thread: 5 | Exiting Initialize for RosettaReportUploader
2009-09-19 01:45:48Z | Module: Initializer | Thread: 5 | The New Team Project Wizard successfully Initialized the plug-in Microsoft.ProjectCreationWizard.Reporting.
2009-09-19 01:45:48Z | Module: WSS | Thread: 5 | Entering Initialize in WssSiteCreator
2009-09-19 01:45:48Z | Module: WSS | Thread: 5 | Site information: Title = "TestProject"  Description = "This team project was created based on the 'MSF for Agile Software Development - v4.2' process template."
2009-09-19 01:45:48Z | Module: WSS | Thread: 5 | Base site url: http://TFSServer01:14143/webbplatser
2009-09-19 01:45:48Z | Module: WSS | Thread: 5 | Admin site url: http://TFSServer01:16183/_vti_adm/admin.asmx
---begin Exception entry---
Time: 2009-09-19 01:46:27 Z 
Module: Initialize 
Event Description: TF30207: Initialization for plugin "Microsoft.ProjectCreationWizard.Portal 'failed 
Exception Type: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.PcwException 
Exception Message: The client discovered that content-type of request is text / html; charset = utf-8, but the text / xml expected. 
The request failed with error message: 
-- 
Unable to connect to the configuration database.
--.
Stack Trace:
   vid Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WssSiteCreator.CheckPermissions(ProjectCreationContext ctxt)
   vid Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WssSiteCreator.Initialize(ProjectCreationContext context)
   vid Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.EngineStarter.InitializePlugins(MsfTemplate template, PcwPluginCollection pluginCollection)
--   Inner Exception   --
Exception Type: System.InvalidOperationException 
Exception Message: The client discovered that content-type of request is text / html; charset = utf-8, but the text / xml expected. 
The request failed with error message:
--
Unable to connect to the configuration database.

--.
Stack Trace:
   vid System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   vid System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   vid Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Proxy.Portal.Admin.GetLanguages()
   vid Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WssSiteCreator.CheckPermissions(ProjectCreationContext ctxt)
-- end Inner Exception --
--- end Exception entry ---
```

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/950610

Comment: But how do you change the permissions on windows/temp?

Answer (score 1):

i had same issue a while back and my solution to this was to reinstall application, stupid but it worked for me...